# Удаление файла со сроком годности

Tags: php

Удалите вопрос пожалуйста.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Либо код отработал, либо у Вас ошибка намного проще, чем тут пытаются "угадать" =)

```
$dir = opendir('/home/p119972/www/cougardesign.ru/img/');
$j=0;
while($file[] = readdir($dir))
{
 if($file == '.' || $file == '..' || is_dir('/home/p119972/www/cougardesign.ru/img/' . $file)){continue;}
 $time_sec=time();
 $fp='/home/p119972/www/cougardesign.ru/img/'.$file[$j];
 $time_file[$j]=filemtime($fp);
 $time[$j]=$time_sec-$time_file[$j];
 if ($time[$j] > 3600)
  {
   unlink('/home/p119972/www/cougardesign.ru/img/'.$file[$j]);  
  }
 $j=$j+1;
}
```

КТО за Вас будет путь-то до файла указывать?? :)

зыж с рекурсивностью этот код конечно не будет работать, но направление в поиске ошибки я Вам дал ;)

ззыж вот это вроде как будет работать, не проверял...

```
<?
$expire_time = 3600; // Время через которое файл считается устаревшим (в сек.)
$dir = "/home/p119972/www/cougardesign.ru/img/";
// проверяем, что $dir - каталог
if (is_dir($dir)) {
// открываем каталог
    if ($dh = opendir($dir)) {
    // читаем и выводим все элементы
    // от первого до последнего
        while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
            // текущее время
            $time_sec=time();
            // время изменения файла
            $time_file=filemtime($dir . $file);
            // тепрь узнаем сколько прошло времени (в секундах)
            $time=$time_sec-$time_file;
            $unlink = $dir.$file;
            if (is_file($unlink)){
                if ($time>$expire_time){
                    if (unlink($unlink)){
                        echo 'Файл удален';
                    }else {
                        echo 'Ошибка при удалении файла';
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        // закрываем каталог
        closedir($dh);
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: при указании командам просто имени файла оно будет икать его в ТЕКУЩЕЙ директории, где работает скрипт. при использовании opendir пхп не будет там ничего искать ;)

Comment: На самый поверхностный взгляд ошибки там как минимум ещё 2, и обе связаны с $file. Массив тут вообще не нужен - это раз, к $file обращаются не как к массиву - два, и индекс $j отстаёт от реального содержимого массива - три. Ну, использование строки вместо переменной или дефайна в качестве имени каталога уже мелочи :-)

Comment: полностью согласен)

мой код рассматривать не как точное решение, а как направление телодвижений в сторону решения ;)

Comment: "Всё" тут может работать ровно до первого каталога. И как только он встретится, тут же проявляются две грубые ошибки в коде. Какие - см. выше, подробно разжёвывать не буду. Чтобы их увидеть, нужно хоть немного подумать что именно делает каждая строчка кода. Могу только намекнуть, что обе они связаны с $file.

Comment: @HappyCougar ну так вы на ошибку то посмотрите :) ни .. ни . вы не удалите ибо это НЕ файл, для этого и есть проверка

        if($file == '.' || $file == '..' || is_dir('/home/p119972/www/cougardesign.ru/img/' . $file)){continue;}

вам же пхп и пишет, что .. это директория.

Comment: Только эта проверка работать не будет, отсюда и попытка удалить каталог :)

Comment: хотя да, тут эта проверка не прокатит)
ну вообщем, в инете полно примеров, высшим образованием обладать не надо... ;)

Answer (score 5):

Нет времени, к сожалению ,писать код сейчас, но надеюсь помогу кусками.

1) Код на перебор файлов в папке:

```
$dir = opendir('path/to/dir');  
$count = 0;  
while($file = readdir($dir)){  
    if($file == '.' || $file == '..' || is_dir('path/to/dir' . $file)){  
        continue;  
    }  
    //some action  
}
```

2) Определение времени существования файла:

```
$time_sec=time();  
// время изменения файла  
$time_file=filemtime("file.html");  
// тепрь узнаем сколько прошло времени (в секундах)  
$time=$time_sec-$time_file;
```

3) Удалить файл можно функцией `unlink(string $filename [, resource $context ])`. 
Вот ссылка на ман: [unlink](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.unlink.php).

Алгоритм, я думаю, построить труда не составит.

Comment: Обязательно попробую. Но как в таком цикле брать имя файла?

Comment: Код номер 1), переменная $file...

Comment: Кстати, зачем строка с обработкой точек? Я никогда не работал с файлами так плотно, что бы знать...

Comment: В данном случае обработка точек не нужна, достаточно is_dir(). А  точки - это вообще-то азы: ссылка на каталог верхнего уровня (..) и текущий (.) :-) Проверка нужна при рекурсивном обходе каталогов, чтобы не зациклиться.

Кстати, код-то получился рабочий? Ошибок там есть :)